# Show Simple Product attribute on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, product-attribute, simple-product

I want to show a custom_attribute of a simple product only.

I need this on the home page.

I want to foreach loop the 10 highest priced configurable products and show the lowest priced simple product custom_attribute

I can do it on the product page itself with its own simple products just fine with the following:

```
    if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"): ?>
    <?php 
        $childIds=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getChildrenIds($_product->getId());
        $simple_collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->
        addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' =>  array_values($childIds[0])))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc');   
                // add  in stock to collection
        $cond = array(
            '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
            '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=0',
        );

            $cond[] = '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1';

        $simple_collection->joinField(
            'inventory_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'is_in_stock',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '(' . join(') OR (', $cond) . ')'
        );

foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ 

        echo $sample_attribute
        echo $sample_attribute_2

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understood what you need, but you could try using somethig like this in your loop:

```
$top10 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$top10
    ->addPriceData()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)
    ->addAttributeToSort('price', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->setCurPage(1);

foreach ($top10 as $product) {   
    $simpleCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
        ->getUsedProductCollection($product);

    $simpleCollection
        ->addPriceData()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('price', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);

    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
        ->addInStockFilterToCollection($simpleCollection);

    $lowestSimple = $simpleCollection->getFirstItem();
    echo $lowestSimple->getAttributeName();
}
```

---

2nd part of your question in comments (how to add category filter):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$top10 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$top10
    ->addPriceData()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)
    ->addAttributeToSort('price', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->setCurPage(1);

foreach ($top10 as $product) {  
    $simpleCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
        ->getUsedProductCollection($product);

    $simpleCollection
        ->addPriceData()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('price', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);

    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
        ->addInStockFilterToCollection($simpleCollection);

    $lowestSimple = $simpleCollection->getFirstItem();
    echo $lowestSimple->getAttributeName();
}
```

Comment: I cant include this into the code I have for the product page as it doesn't work on the homepage. I need it to be independent. I need to get the 10 highest priced products and show the custom attribute for the lowest price simple product of each of the 10 configurables

Comment: Ok, I modified my code, see if it works. I did not test it.

Comment: This is some amazing coding. Works great. thank you so much. Just one more thing. If I wanted to filter by category also, would this be possible?

Comment: See my addendum.

Comment: I added `$categoryId = 2;` and my custom_attribute but page isn't working.

Comment: $categoryId = 2? Are you sure? 2 should be the catalog root. BTW: Category must be configured as anchor if you expect to see subcategoy products too.

Comment: ah yes, It was 4 not 2 but there is a problem in the code as the page no longer displays anything below the code

Comment: Check your error log, you probably have something

Comment: I have it working now. Removed `$childIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
        ->getTypeInstance()
        ->getUsedProductIds();` Thank you :)

Comment: Ops, sorry... it was a cut and paste error ;) . I fixed it. Please the question mark as solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36071/discussion-between-mike-tim-turner-and-riccardot).